# How to solve for the amount the equilibrium was disturbed with an ICE table?

Tags: equilibrium

On a recent quiz, we were asked the following question:

> $$\ce{A(aq) + B(aq) <=> C(aq)}$$
>   At $\pu{298 K}$, the equilibrium amounts of each of the component are as follows: $[\ce{A}] = \pu{0.125 M}$, $[\ce{B}] = \pu{0.400 M}$, $[\ce{C}] = \pu{1.200 M}$. At $\pu{298 K}$, the system is perturbed by increasing the concentration of $\ce{B}$ by adding $X$ amount. When equilibrium is re-established, the concentration of $[\ce{C}] = \pu{1.250 M}$. The volume of the system remains unchanged. How much $X$ (in $\pu{M}$) was added to the system?

The correct answer for this is $\pu{0.344 M}$, but I'm struggling to understand the setup for how the ICE table would work, since my original construction would mean the $X$ value is just $\pu{0.05 M}$:

\begin{array}{lccc}
\text{Stage}       & \ce{A (aq)}      & \ce{B (aq)}   & \ce{C (aq)} \\\hline
\text{Initial}     & \pu{0.125 M}     & \pu{0.4 M}    & \pu{1.2 M}  \\
\text{Change}      & -X               & +X            & +X          \\
\text{Equilibrium} & \pu{0.125 M} - X & \pu{0.4 M} +X & \pu{1.25 M} \\
\end{array}

But this does not seem to be right. Have I set up my initial values incorrectly? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The change for B should be -X, just like for A, the other reactant. And, as given in one of the answers, you know what X is from the last column.

Comment: This exercise is horrible, it uses terminology which is incorrect. You have been given equilibrium ***concentrations*** not amounts. Then the equilibrium is perturbed by adding $X$ amount which is again supposed to be a concentration, but the volume stays the same. That question was clearly posed by someone who has never done (and/or studied) chemistry. ***Please add a source (citation, not just a screenshot) for this garbage exercise.***

Answer (score 2):

The key insight here is that the amount added, "$X$", is NOT the typical "$x$" in a standard ICE table. The typical $x$ represents the changes in concentration *toward equilibrium*. The disturbance $X$ is a perturbation *away from equilibrium*. The initial state of your ICE table should be the state at which you will begin moving to equilibrium, i.e., with $X$ already added to [B]. Try starting with [B]+$X$ as your initial concentration for B in the ICE table and proceed as usual (I encourage you to actually try it this way). And to find the value of $X$ just use the information given about how [C] increased, as I'm sure you had no trouble doing.

Comment: Ah, I suspected something like that may have been at play. Thank you for explaining the theory and clearing up that ICE table is only once you start moving towards equilibrium. I'll keep this in mind for the exam!

Answer (score -1):

Calculation of $K_c$ using initial concentrations

$K_c = \dfrac{1.2}{0.125 \times 0.4} = 24l mol^{-1}$

```
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+
|    Stage    |    A(aq)    |  B(aq)       | C(aq)    |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+
| Initial     | 0.125M      | 0.4M + X     | 1.2M     |
| Change      |    -y       |    -y        |   +y     |
| Equilibrium | 0.125M  - y | 0.4M + X - y | 1.2M + y |
+-------------+-------------+--------------+----------+
```

Final concentration of C = 1.25 M, $\therefore$   y= 0.05 M. Since $K_c$ won't change, thus

24 = $\dfrac{1.25}{0.075 \times (0.35 + X)}$

$\implies$ X = 0.3444 M

Comment: The way the change row is usually interpreted, it should reflect changes due to the chemical reaction, so every species should change according to stoichiometry. You could have the initial B at 0.4M + x, and have -0.05, -0.05, +0.05 as change. The equilibrium row is correct, so you get the correct answer.

Comment: This is not really an answer, it's just a table without much of an explanation; I can't follow what is presented here. We have given up the stance on only providing hint answers for homework-like questions. It is overall better to have a worked example with no questions left to ask, than a hint which produces even more questions. (This was flagged NAA, so the above was a service announcement.)

Comment: @Martin - マーチン I updated my answer, is this format correct?

Comment: It's better, but still not good. Please never ever omit units. Also, while some people think and speak in formulas, quite a few don't. Those who do are usually not asking such kind of questions. Therefore, adding explanations would be a good idea.

Comment: @Martin - マーチン questions like this have little to explain, I don't know how to explain the working. If you could help me by editing the answer.....

Comment: I find questions like these (I mean the original exercise, not the one by OP) awful, because they don't actually make any sense. Please see my comment to the question. In general, there is much, much to explain. You should start with writing the reaction equation again, then start deriving the general formula for the equilibrium constant, then explain the variables used (and never ever, not in a single instant omit any unit) and then insert them and do the calculation. Explain how to set up the table. And please, write actual sentences and nut just phrases.